# Restarting a function after calling another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a Python function to automate a software program. The workflow looks something like this:

```
def main():
    while True:
        do A
        if A is not done correctly for more than 100 times:
            reboot()

    while True:
        do B
        if B is not done correctly for more than 100 times:
            reboot()

    while True:
        do C
        if C is not done correctly for more than 100 times:
            reboot()

def reboot():
    restart the software program
```

The problem I am currently having is that e.g. if B is not done correctly, it will trigger the reboot. After the reboot is executed, it will bring me back to the while loop that does B.

What I really need is the script to always start from A after a reboot.

I have done my research and know there is no GoTo in Python, and people suggest using while loops for this kind of applications, but I somehow can't see how it can work in my situation. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "restart the software program" ? Starting the `main()` again? Your code is not ever using `B` or `C` - because you reboot() - you are never breaking from `while True: do A`. Please write a runnable [mcve] - this pseudocode does not help us to help you. For autostarting you normally would use a scheduler that runs `python yourfile.py` on startup - maybe add a "Am I currently running" check to your program and if so execute the instance immediately. Then schedule it to run every _N_ minutes. As long as one instance runs, no other will proceeed to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto is evil and can easily create some big execution flaws, that's why it isn't used anymore in most professional environments.

Let's assume your, A, B or C is some sort of condition, in that case you could create a function that evaluates that condition, though it largely depends on what the condition is.

Why not just call the function with the proper condition based on whatever business logic you have. Here it is what I'm suggesting:

```
def do_the_work(...condition params):
    while True:
        # do the actual work and evaluate the conditions
        # if the conditions don't pass for X times
        # then just break this loop and return


while True:
    # main business logic here
    # will decide how to call the
    # do_the_work function
    # meaning, deciding what params to send to it
```

The explanation is that the main while loop defined at the end of the script will be your "main" that will redo the work every time the "do_the_work" ends it's while loop and returns.